# Some websites disable my back button, how can I still use it?

Tags: firefox

Some websites disable the back button, and don't let you escape back from it. Is there a way to selectively disable this disablement of back button? I feel it offensive, and get frustrated when I encounter such websites. I use Firefox 4.

Comment: can you provide us with an example of a website that does this?

Comment: I've seen websites breaking the back button functionality because of inconsistent programming, but never in a way that you **couldn't** actually click the button.

Comment: @Christofian I don't have an example right now, but I will come back when I encounter again. @slhck You can click the button, but it does not take you to anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: the pages have a "Meta refresh" tag or a JavaScript scriptlet, which gets activated as soon as you go "back" to them. You cannot disable these "features", as they have many legitimate uses, but you can skip the offending page by right-clicking on the "Back" button and jumping two pages back.

Comment: I see. I will do right clicking on the back button. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. Also, there is no "legitimate use" for websites to disable it when I decide that I want to use the back-button. I consider it a hostile behaviour of that website - it's my back button after all, in my UI, so why should external websites be able to control that? I never gave them permission to do so.