# How to disable 'Go back one page' Button in Firefox?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, firefox

I am using Firefox 4 and higher versions.

We have a web application which will mis-behave if a user hits the back button on Firefox tool bar to 'go back one page'. So I am looking for a way to disable (grey out) this button. This question looking for exact reverse behaviors discussed in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/280863/disableing-back-button-break).

I am looking for a solution in Ubuntu (10.10) and/or Windows as client operating systems.

Comment: As answered in the link you posted, it is not possible to disable that button. On the other hand, maybe you should fix your web application to work well with the back button?

Comment: As @Jin said. This is just a typical example of bad web design. You can't disable this functionality for every client (unless you have maybe *total* control over your clients).

Comment: This is an intranet application, so there is total control over ALL the clients.

Comment: I am looking for either a means for disabling it in clients or disabling it from the web application so that when clients open it, you cannot use back button to go back one page.

Comment: Is it only when this webpage is open? Or would entirely disabling the back button be acceptable?

Comment: Either would be fine, since this is the only application the users may use here and browsers will not be used for internet browsing in general.Many of the Users of the application are not very IT-enabled, so we needed to disable back space for application to behave normally.

Answer (score 1):

You could diable the back buttons using a GPO.

Another way is to simply load a new window and to set the new window to not have a toolbar. So if there is a particular set of pages that you want to ensure the user cannot click Back on, just load the first page in that process in a new window with no toolbars.

or you could try this:

```
<html><head>
<title>noBack</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function noBack(){window.history.forward();}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if(event.persisted)noBack();" onunload="">
...blabla...
</body></html>
```

This code is taken from [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=630479)

Comment: Only disadvantage I see here is that each page of the application explicitly  needs to be programmed to disallow back button. I would still look to see if I can disable it altogether from browser.

Comment: Have you looked into the option of disabling it through a GPO?

Comment: By GPO do you mean, Group Policy in windows ? I did not yet, the primary OS in use is Ubuntu, but I am looking for windows solution as well. Do you know where I can disable it in GPO?

Comment: I've never used GPO's for Firefox but this should get you started: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gpo-for-firefox/